# Applescript app to change the size of the foremost app's top most window to arbitrary size

Tags: applescript

I want to write an app using applescrpt (saved with the .app extension) that whenever executed, will find out the foremost windows of the foremost application and resize/reposition it to a specific size. I have written the following, which works in Script Editor, but then it does not work on other windows, when I execute the app via spotlight.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to first application process whose frontmost is true
    set frontAppWindow to first window of frontApp
    set size of frontAppWindow to {800, 600}
end tell
```

This results in the error:

```
Can't get window 1 of «class pcap» "lhalf"' of application
"System Events". Invalid index.
System Events got an error: Can't get window 1 of application process "lhalf".
Invalid index. (-1719)
```

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
    tell process frontApp
        set frontWindow to first window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true
        set position of frontWindow to {0, 22}
        set size of frontWindow to {800, 600}
    end tell
end tell
```

This gives an error.

```
Can't get window 1 of «class pros» "lhalf" of application
"System Events" whose value of
attribute "AXMain" = true. Invalid
index.
System Events got an error: Can't get window 1 of process "lhalf" whose value
of attribute "AXMain" = true. Invalid
index. (-1719)
```

I have named my app `lhalf.app`. When I execute this app via spotlight, it think the foremost app is itself, and not the app that is currently on the screen. How can I remedy this? Or are there any other alternate better ways to code the entire thing from scratch?

Comment: Not saying that it will solve your problem but for an application to use the method you have above (i.e. ui scripting), it requires 'assistive access', which means that you should add it in the security system preferences. And yes, when run this way it is the frontmost application — and your app doesn't have windows, hence the -1719 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an **AppleScript** applet, this following code should work.

*I added a delay of five seconds at the beginning of the code, which allows you to bring the target application frontmost first (for example: clicking on the app's icon in the Dock)*

```
--The delay gives you time to bring target app to front (clicking app's icon in the Dock) 
delay 5

set thePosition to {0, 22}
set theSize to {800, 600}
set theBounds to {thePosition} & {theSize}

tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of (process 1 whose it is frontmost) to ¬
        set {position, size} to theBounds
end tell
```

However, I think an easier and quicker solution would be to remove the delay command from the above code, save it as "lhalf.scpt" in your /Users/***YOUR_SHORT_NAME***/Library/Scripts folder.  Then you can just directly run the "lhalf.scpt" from Scripts menu in your System Status bar.

[image]

If your Script menu in your System Status Bar is not enabled, this following AppleScript code will enable that for you.

```
tell application "AppleScript Utility"
    if not Script menu enabled then
        set Script menu enabled to true
        set application scripts position to top
        set show Computer scripts to false
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as a script.app† and it sets the `bounds` property of the front window of the frontmost application. Basically, it hides the script app, gets the new frontmost app and then sets its front window's bounds.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmostProcess to first process whose frontmost is true
    set visible of frontmostProcess to false
    repeat while (frontmostProcess is frontmost)
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    
    set SecondFrontmost to first process whose frontmost is true
    set nameSecondFrontmost to name of SecondFrontmost
    if nameSecondFrontmost is "firefox" then set nameSecondFrontmost to "Firefox Nightly"
end tell

tell application (nameSecondFrontmost) -- use with .app from menu or dock
    activate
    set bounds of window 1 to {4, 24, 984, 324}
end tell
```

Adapted from this macscripter post:
[Get second frontmost app / processes in activation order](https://www.macscripter.net/t/get-second-frontmost-app-processes-in-activation-order/60740/2)

NB I use the nightly variant of firefox but since all variants possess the same process name —which differs from the application name— I added the line to sort it out.

If the app in question doesn't have resizable windows (e.g. EasyFind) or a scripting dictionary (e.g. Fission) then it will generate a -10006 error.

It can be modified to work as a script (rather than an app) by working with the name of the 'frontmostProcess' rather than 'secondFrontmost'.

† Export as `Application` into the User Scripts folder